# image in panel whithout scroll bar and move image (top and down) in panel whith javascript function

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I loaded a picture in a panel (ASP Panel).size of my image is bigger than size of panel. i want my panel without scroll bar? how to do that? and i want move image (top and down) in panel with javascript function. is it possible? how can i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add overflow: hidden; to the panel, if it has a set height and width that the image is expanding out of.

For the second part, I think you're going to need to give us a little more information

Comment: i want move image with javascript and be sure that its not go out of panel

Comment: Alex is it possible to turn off scroll bar ? with overflow: hidden; ? in your example when image goes out of panel scroll bar shows, i dont want that happen. and i want move with button click

Comment: If you have a fixed height and width with overflow: hidden; you shouldn't see scroll bars as that is the nature of overflow: hidden; it should hide anything that overflows the boundaries of it's containment